# What happens when multiplying two residue classes element-wise

Tags: number-theory

Now I'm stuck with a problem like this:

There are two sets of integers:$A=\{kn+r_1|k\in\mathbb{Z}\}$,and $B=\{ln+r_2|l\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ where $r_1,r_2\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $0\leq r_1,r_2<n$

Then what is the set $\{ij|i\in A,j\in B\}$ exactly?

I know that all the members in the set are equivalent to $r_1r_2$ mod n.

But I don't know what is in it exactly.

Like if $A = \{...,-10,-4,2,8,14,...\}$ and $B = \{...,-8,-2,4,10,16,...\}$, then even if 2 is equivalent to 2 mod 6,but 2 doesn't appear in the set of all the products.14 is also not in it too.

I'm just wondering what numbers are in that set.

Pls give me an answer.Thanks very very much!

Comment: Well, not all the numbers that are equal to $r_1r_2 \pmod n$ are going to be in the resulting set. By definition, it will only be those numbers that can be split into two factors, with one of them being equal to $r_1 \pmod n$ and the other to $r_2 \pmod n$. I'm not sure there's a nicer characterization than that.

Comment: @ynwarcs Yes.I'm just suspecting now that there isn't a nicer characterization than what you mentioned.Because when factorizations come into number theory problems,they could become REALLY hard.